# How to add a ptr (reverse DNS) record for office 365

Tags: office365

I am a bit stuck. I have set up an Office 365 installation with the proper settings. But when I send an email I get the message. 
Incorrectly configured PTR record. All the DNS settings are correct (at least that indicates office 365).

The website is running on a different server of course. And we do not use the nameserver of Office 365.

So my question, where do I need to add the PTR record and what value does it have?

I have added the DNS record below :)

[image]

Comment: I guess your running an application to send emails so more info is needed, 
Which network node returns with the PTR error? 
Do you receive the error message in an NDR?
Have you tried to analyze the message trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Exchange 365 official documentation, it looks like this behaviour is by design. Exchange 365 does not support configuring the PTR because it is using multiple IP addresses and it seems that because of DNS limitations, they could not list all IPs in PTR records.

Though quite frankly, according to the example, I can't figure out why they need to use different names for the HELO and the PTR...

[More information can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/troubleshoot/antispam-and-protection/cannot-send-emails-to-external-recipients)

Answer (score 1):

I am just investigating email delivery problems for a customer with Microsoft 365 and came across the below extremely useful sites which explain how to check PTR records and what they mean in the first place.

PTR records are stored in the .arpa TLD zone which is managed bei IANA. Some ISPs are able to store records there and they don't do it without good reasons, it seems.

In-depth reading: [The PTR record](https://www.nslookup.io/learning/dns-record-types/ptr/) and [How to lookup PTR records](https://www.nslookup.io/ptr-lookup/), both at  at nslookup.io - these guys know their way around!

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigation a bit around your question and found that not all the DNS providers allows to register PTR records, example: Freenom and GoDaddy do the job for their customers. Cantact your DNS provider for help if the PTR type isn't listed in the DNS console

Comment: It would be nice with some details about what to fill in (and possibly why) if PTR is available as a type in above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

if the domain is on HOSTGATOR and you change the DNS for handling emails to office 365. The solution is go toHOSTGATOR  CPANEL > email routing > select domain (that is used on office365) and change it to remote.